# Proving that a circle is constructed by points $C$ such that the ratio of its distances to $A$ and $B$ is constant and different than $1$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I found this problem in Pogorélov's *Elemental Geometry* (Spanish edition) and couldn't find how to solve it (sorry for the bad Egnlish):

> Prove a circle is constructed by the points $C$ such that the ratio of the distance to points $A$ and $B$ is constant and different than $1$.
>
> Suggestion: the bisector of the interior and exterior angles of vertex $C$ of triangle $ABC$ are perpendicular. Cross the line $AB$ always at the same points for any point $C$.

For what I understand the problem is about showing a circle is a case of an ellipse, but at this point in the book no ellipse definition is given.

Any ideas?

Comment: See Wikipedia's ["Circles of Apollonius" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius), specifically the section "Apollonius' definition of a circle".

Comment: If the internal angle bisector of $ \angle C$ meets $AB$ at $P$ and external angle bisector meets at $Q$ then draw a circle with diameter $PQ$. Now move point $C$ on this circle. What happens to the ratio $AC:BC$?

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2}\div\sqrt{(x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2}=c$. Clear fractions, square both sides, combine like terms, manipulate until you get the equations of a circle.

Comment: It is an hyperbola, if I read properly the constrains on C as related to A and B. Try and draw it.

Comment: No ellipse here: in the case of a conic section, the fixed ratio is between the distances from a fixed point (focus) AND A FIXED LINE (directrix).

Comment: @Moti, it's a hyperbola if the *difference* of the distances is constant, but here the question is about the *ratio* of the distances.

Comment: You are right - it is an Ellipse

Comment: @Moti, have you tried following the steps in my first comment?

Comment: @Moti, are you still here?

Comment: Yes... and I see that the circle seems to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to find the locus of points $C$ such that $AC/BC = k$.

I claim that this locus is the set $C_k$ defined as follows:

- $C_0$ is the point $A$ and $C_\infty$ the point $B$.
- $C_1$ is the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$.
- For other values of $k$, $C_k$ is the circle with diameter $DE$, where $D$ and $E$ are the points respectively dividing the segment $AB$ internally and externally in the ratio $k$. (That is: $D$ and $E$ are on line $AB$, we have $AD/BD = AE/BE = k$, point $D$ belongs to segment $AB$ but point $E$ doesn't.)

It is easy to see that the sets $C_k$ are pairwise disjoint. (Any two diameters situated on opposite sides of the midpoint of $AB$ are disjoint, while any two on the same side are such that one is contained in the interior of the other.)

Hence in order to prove that each locus is equal to $C_k$, it is enough to prove that it is contained in $C_k$.

We may assume $k \ne 0, 1, \infty$ since these cases are clear.

Let $C$ be such that $AC/BC = k$. We are to show that $C$ belongs to circle $C_k$.

If $C$ is situated on line $AB$, this is clear since only two points, $D$ and $E$, divide segment $AB$ in the ratio $k$. Assume therefore that $C$ is not on line $AB$.

By the angle bisector theorem applied to triangle $ABC$, the internal and external bisectors of $\angle C$ must meet $AB$ at $D$ and $E$, respectively. Since these bisectors are perpendicular, the angle $DCE$ must be a right angle. Therefore $C$ must belong to the circle with diameter $DE$, as required.